# Alphanum - alphanum sorting

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, comparator

I have input like this

```
Online Add-on 3 GB 2015
Online Add-on 1.5 GB 2015
Online Add-on 12 GB 2015
Online Add-on 6 GB
Online Add-on 375 MB 2015
Online Add-on 750 MB 2014
```

I have tried **alphanum** sorting which is given in this  [link](http://www.davekoelle.com/files/AlphanumComparator.java) and it gives me output as shown below.

```
Online Add-on 1.5 GB 2015
Online Add-on 3 GB 2015
Online Add-on 6 GB
Online Add-on 12 GB 2015
Online Add-on 375 MB 2015
Online Add-on 750 MB 2014
```

But, for better **human readability** I need output like as shown below where if year exists then based on the year lower MB has to come first and then lower GB

```
Online Add-on 750 MB 2014
Online Add-on 375 MB 2015
Online Add-on 6 GB
Online Add-on 1.5 GB 2015
Online Add-on 3 GB 2015
Online Add-on 12 GB 2015
```

Any way to do this in Java???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337682/sorting-alphanumeric-strings-java take reference from this once

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade Please go through the question properly - I have tried all those things and my requirement is different. Please let me know if question is not clear

Comment: esp. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14337783/2310289 You will need to split your line and compare on the 3rd element

Comment: Define a class that extends `Comparable`, that has two pieces of data: number of megabytes (or number of bytes) and year.  Define a comparator that compares the year first, then compares the megabytes if the years are equal.  When you read your strings, use `split` and look at the 4th element to see whether you need to multiply the 3rd element by 1000 or not.  (Adjust this if you also want to allow KB, TB, etc.).  Create an object for each input string.  Sort using the comparator.  Google for any tutorial on sorting in Java to get more details.

Comment: That does *"if year exists then based on the year"* mean? If you have `10 MB 2014`, `900 MB 2014`, `20 MB 2015`, and `800 MB 2015`, where would a 5th value of `500 MB` (no year) be sorted? If you're sorting by year first, then sizes will be all scattered, so where does a "no year" value belong?

Comment: @ScaryWombat  I can try that

Comment: @ajb thanks for the detailed comment. I can try this

Comment: @Andreas nice catch. In that case, without year could go first.. I will update the quesiton

Comment: @RavindraDevadiga You have a very weird definition of "first", when you put the line without year in the *third* position, rather than first. `1st != 3rd`

Comment: I'd rather parse the string into meaning objects, and sort using the objects. E.g. make a class with `String rawString; int size; SizeUnit unit; Year year`.  It should then be trivial to write comparison with these attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first format the info in a cannonical way, define a format for this:
**"Online Add-on 750 MB 2014"** like **"frefix size magnitude year"**

then define a class for that (Capac in the example below)

the magnitude can be an Enum (Unit in the exampl.) override properly hashcode and equ.

then make a list with those Capac objects and sort it with a predefined comparator using double criteria, 1st by magnitde and then by size...

## Example:

```
public class Capac {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String arr[] = { "Online Add-on 750 MB 2014", "Online Add-on 375 MB 2015", "Online Add-on 1.5 GB 2015",
                "Online Add-on 3 GB 2015", "Online Add-on 6 GB 2015", "Online Add-on 12 GB 2015" };

        final List<Capac> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final String string : arr) {
            myList.add(new Capac(string));
        }
        System.out.println(myList);
        // sort
        Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Capac>() {
            
            @Override
            public int compare(Capac o1, Capac o2) {
                if (o1.unit == o2.unit) {
                    return Double.compare(o1.size, o2.size);
                } else {
                    
                    return Integer.compare(o1.unit.ordinal(), o2.unit.ordinal());
                }

            }
        });
        System.out.println(myList);
    }
    
    private final double size;
    private final int year;
    private final Unit unit;
    private final String prefix;

    public Capac(String ss) {
        final String[] rr = ss.split(" ");
        prefix = rr[0] + " " + rr[1];
        size = Double.parseDouble(rr[2]);
        unit = Unit.valueOf(rr[3]);
        year = Integer.parseInt(rr[4]);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return prefix + " " + size + " " + unit + " " + year;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((prefix == null) ? 0 : prefix.hashCode());
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(size);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + ((unit == null) ? 0 : unit.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + year;
        return result;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final Capac other = (Capac) obj;
        if (prefix == null) {
            if (other.prefix != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!prefix.equals(other.prefix))
            return false;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(size) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.size))
            return false;
        if (unit != other.unit)
            return false;
        if (year != other.year)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    
}

enum Unit {
    KB, MB, GB, TB
}
```

the outoput will look like

> [Online Add-on 750.0 MB 2014, Online Add-on 375.0 MB 2015, Online
> Add-on 1.5 GB 2015, Online Add-on 3.0 GB 2015, Online Add-on 6.0 GB
> 2015, Online Add-on 12.0 GB 2015]

and

> [Online Add-on 375.0 MB 2015, Online Add-on 750.0 MB 2014, Online
> Add-on 1.5 GB 2015, Online Add-on 3.0 GB 2015, Online Add-on 6.0 GB
> 2015, Online Add-on 12.0 GB 2015]